Moderation in SEM when Scalar and Metric Noninvariance
I would like to know if it is methodologically sound for me to do a moderation analysis, interacting a latent variable and an observed binary variable (LV1 * X ==>Y) when I have metric and scalar noninvariance for the latent variable (LV1) between groups designated by the observed variable (X) - but configural invariance.
My understanding is if I have metric or scalar noninvariance, I cannot compare latent means or other parameter estimates between groups. But a moderation would be testing how the demographic variable (X) relates to the relationship between the Latent Variable and the Observed Outcome variable, so moderation estimates might not be very "dependent" on the measurement invariance of the latent variable. I would greatly appreciate any thoughts you have on this.

It is hard to provide specific advice without knowing more about your specific application.  If you provide a path diagram and describe which parameter(s) appear equal across groups (i.e., a partial-invariance model), then it is possible that valid comparisons could still be made across groups.
